# How to properly use define and !defined to secure pages from direct access?

Tags: php

I am trying to secure php files from direct access. I've defined "TESTCONST" constant in config.php. And in other files I am checking if it is defined by:

```
if(!defined('TESTCONST')) { header('Location: /'); }
```

But this won't work if I include config.php right above this, cause it will be defined always. So how can I achieve this with define !defined? Here is a bit of structure:

config.php:

```
    <?php

    define('TESTCONST', true);

    .*.. A lot of other configs ...*
```

Some other php file

```
    <?php

    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/core/configs/config.php';

    if(!defined('TESTCONST')) { header('Location: /'); }

    .*.. A lot of other things ...*
```

**P.S. Note: I have to include config.php file, because it contains configs, that are required by every function in php files.**

Comment: *But this won't work if I include config.php right above this, cause it will be defined always.* - You use `defined` to make sure the files haven't been changed and if they have you can prevent execution as the config is incorrect..Even if it hasn't happened it could happen hence the check is important.

Comment: So what is the proper way to use this combination: define and !defined&

Comment: Define *proper* way.

Comment: Just drop the require. If it is not already imported, `TESTCONST` won't be defined so you redirect, as expected, if `TESTCONST` is defined (so your script was not called directly) the `config.php` has already been imported by another script, so no need to require it.

Comment: Well, most of php files are standalone and are called by JQuery POST. I mean, that this php files aren't included or required. So they NEED to import config.php.. I guess you understand me..

Comment: The issue here stems from the fact that the OP does not understand the fundamental reason that `defined` is used, it is there for that one day when someone changes something which erases `TESTCONST` (which subsequently would break everything) but instead of showing errors it just prevents the page from loading as the `if` statement takes care of it all.

Comment: @AndrewGG Your jQuery POST request is a direct access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First way : with your `config.php`

In every PHP script that is allowed to direct access, require it :

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/core/configs/config.php';
```

In every PHP script you want to protect from direct access, check the constant :

```
if(!defined('TESTCONST')) { header('Location: /'); }
```

(if it is defined, `config.php` is already required so no need for `require_once`)

## Second way : with another script file

Create another PHP file for the definition of the constant (here, let's call it `access.php`)

```
<?php define('TESTCONST', true);
```

In every PHP script that is allowed to direct access, require it :

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/core/configs/config.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/core/configs/access.php';
```

In every PHP script you want to protect from direct access, check the constant :

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/core/configs/config.php';
if(!defined('TESTCONST')) { header('Location: /'); }
```

Comment: the issue here is that that is simply not a good way to control access to your scripts

Comment: I agree. But the OP asked how to do this that way. There are many better ways to do this, but they are all off-topic. Maybe he can't access NGinX/Apache/Other config files, maybe he was asked to do it this way.

Comment: How would they be off-topic? A better option which is suggested is never off-topic as long as it is within reason.

Comment: Reason why am I using define !defined? I saw a lot of CMS that uses exactly this technic.

Comment: @Script47 Because IMHO when someone asks `How to do this with A ?` and you answer `You have to do this with B`, it is not what he asked for.

Comment: @LP154 this site is a great tool for learning, so if someone asks how to do "A" and the community presents alternative solutions (which solve the problem better) then I feel it is on topic, must not be the accepted answer but it's an alternative that the OP might not even be aware of so it's not a wasted information

Comment: I think we are both right. Somebody who must use A will find the answer he is looking for, somebody who can use an alternative solution will find other answers useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to prevent web access to some php files the best way it so deny access from the server. For apache you could use an .htaccess file
set up your files as such:

```
/index.php
/protected/.htaccess
/protected/sensitive_script.php
/protected/not_not_access.php
```

and in the .htaccess

```
Deny from all
```

Comment: my mistake he did say "I am trying to secure php files from direct access." maybe he needs to explain better

Comment: My mistake, not yours, he may potentially be trying that, it isn't very clear to me.